# Regex for Wordle

Tags: regex

using the online word game Wordle (https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/) to sharpen my Regex.

I could use a little help with something that I imagine Regex should solve easily.

- given a 5 letter english word
- given that I know the word begins with `pr`
- given that I know that the letters `outyase` are not found in the word
- given that I know that the letter `i` IS found in the word

what is the correct - most simplified regex?

my limited regex gives is this `^pr.[^outyase][^outyase]$` which is

- a. redundant and
- b. does not include the request to match `i`

any of you Regex Ninjas want to lend a hand, I would be much obliged.

by the way, the correct regex should return two nouns in the english language `prick` and `primi`, you can validate here https://www.visca.com/regexdict/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use this regex with a positive and negative lookahead conditions:

```sh
^pr(?=[a-z]*i)(?![a-z]*[outyase])[a-z]{3}$
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `^`: Start
- `pr`: Match `pr`
- `(?=[a-z]*i)`: Positive lookahead to make sure we have an `i` ahead after 0 or more letters
- `(?![a-z]*[outyase]))`: Negative lookahead to disallow any of the `[outyase]` characters
- `[a-z]{3}`: Match 3 letters

**Demo Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Nice! Just out of curiosity, is it possible to do using Posix extended regular expressions?

Comment: Even with POSIX extended, we won't get lookahead support

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, you can use:

```
^pr([^outyase][^outyase]i|[^outyase]i[^outyase]|i[^outyase][^outyase])$
```

Also, according to your site, there's actually four words matching, not just two:

- prick
- primi
- primp
- prink

Comment: `[^outyase][^outyase]` is `[^outyase]{2}`. Also, `[^outyase]` matches a non-letter, which is a deal-breaker.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
^pr(?!.*[outyase])(?=.*i)[a-z]{3}$
```

`(?!.*[outyase])` means don't match if any of `outyase` is found ahead in the string.

`(?=.*i)` means only match if there is an `i` ahead in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a note for general usage.

For any char position:

```
(?!.*[<BadChars>])(?=.*<firstGoodChar>)(?=.*<SecondGoodChar>)(?=.*<ThirdGoodChar>).*
```

If you know `mghtlc` are bad and `i`, `o`, and `s` are good:

```
^(?!.*[mghtlc])(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*s).*{5}$
```

It's trivial to add a pinned char at the front/back:

```
^b(?!.*[mghtlc])(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*s).*{4}$
```

```
^(?!.*[mghtlc])(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*s).*{4}n$
```

but I'm not sure how the look-ahead would work with a pinned char in the middle given that the found chars (`i`, `o`) can be on either side of the pinned `s`:

NOT WORKING:

```
^(?!.*[mghtlc])(?=.*i)(?=.*o).*{2}s(?!.*[mghtlc])(?=.*i)(?=.*o).*{2}$
```